# how to validate input file with jquery and dataannotation in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, data-annotations

I am sure I am missing something here, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844797/file-input-and-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-2) question to validate a file, here is the sample code

```
public class UpdateSomethingViewModel 
{
    [DisplayName("evidence")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="You must provide evidence")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^abc123.jpg$", ErrorMessage="Stuff and nonsense")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Evidence { get; set; }
}
```

but I don't see any `@Html.FileFor(model => model.Evidence)`

Any ideas?

### Update

I found a simple solution passing attribute type in html attribute collection.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Evidence, new { type = "file" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Evidence)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a simple solution passing attribute `type` in html attribute collection.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Evidence, new { type = "file" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Evidence)
```

Comment: I found that even though this all worked client side the ModelState.IsValid returned false because of the Regex Validator.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid you can't do this using data annotations. You could do this in the controller action that is supposed to handle the request:

Model:

```
public class UpdateSomethingViewModel 
{
    [DisplayName("evidence")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must provide evidence")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Evidence { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(UpdateSomethingViewModel model)
{
    if (model.Evidence != null && model.Evidence.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // the user uploaded a file => validate the name stored
        // in model.Evidence.FileName using your regex and if invalid return a
        // model state error
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(model.Evidence.FileName, @"^abc123.jpg$"))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Evidence", "Stuff and nonsense");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Also note that it is better to use `HttpPostedFileBase` rather than the concrete `HttpPostedFileWrapper` type in your model. It will make your life easier when you are writing unit tests for this controller action.