# How to post back a viewModel to the controller when the Post action is already used for file upload

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have a controller like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
    {
        public MyController(Uow uow)
        {
            ;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            var validationResults = _uow.GetResults(file.FileName, file.InputStream);

            return View(new MyViewModel { Errors = validationResults.Errors, Data = validationResults.Data });
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void Save(MyViewModel viewModel)
        {
            //Save the data
        }
    }
```

This has a view like:

```
@model MyViewModel 

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="file" id="filelabel">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

    <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" disabled="disabled" />
    <img class="loader" id="loader" style="display: none;" alt="Loading..." src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif")" />

    @if (Model != null && Model.Errors.Any())
    {
        foreach (var error in Model.Errors)
        {
            <span class="error">@error</span>
        }    
    }

    <button id="savebtn" >Save</button>

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#file').change(function () {
            alert("in here");
            $('#submitbtn').prop('disabled', false);

        });

        $('#submitbtn').click(function () {

            $('#loader').show();

        });

    });
</script>
```

So what I'm trying to have here is a means to upload a file to the controller. I've achieved this and I received it in the Index Post. I then process this which works fine. I then put the relevant data in the viewModel and redisplay the form.

What I'm wanting is that when the Save button is pressed the Save Post method is called with the populated viewModel. However whenever I push the button it's posting to the Index Post which makes sense.

Could someone please tell me how to retain my file upload and processing code but make it so when I later press the Save button the viewModel is sent to the Save Post method?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to keep these actions separate and not change your current form then you would need a separate form to be able to post asynchronously or not to that other action... which means doing something nasty like updating hidden fields in another form using javascript whenever a change is made to the first form... which is not fool proof due to the many ways that the form fields can be altered without firing certain javascript events.

There is also the possibility of altering the forms action using javascript when the save button is clicked.. but to be honest it all seems too dirty to me and I would use the viewmodel to 1 action approach.

I would suggest having the `HttpPostedFileBase` on your view model and have the Index action handle the validation and saving of the data.

See this example for strongly typed form helpers and annotations: [how to validate input file with jquery and dataannotation in asp.net mvc 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285624/how-to-validate-input-file-with-jquery-and-dataannotation-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Its shows a `HttpPostedFileBase` property with `DataAnnotations`, which you may want to try writing a custom annotation that calls your UOW if you need to validate it that way.. not sure why though?

I would also recommend using the Model.ValidationMessageFor() helper with this too.

The general pattern for actions that receive a view model is like the below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel myViewModel)
{
    try
    {
        // Check your viewmodel is valid
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // not valid so return to the view with the view model as a param
            // The validation message helpers will display the relevant error messages
            return View(myViewModel);
        }

        // modelstate is valid so perform any work i.e. save to database
        // attach any additional information to the view modal to give feedback maybe?
        // or redirect the user to some other page
        return View(myViewModel);
    }
    catch
    {
        // any exceptions then go back to the view and hopefully the validation helpers will kick in
        return View(myViewModel);
    }
}
```

Personally for quick stuff I do this sort of thing, but you can get the idea:

In the view model

```
[DisplayName("Update your image")]
[Required]
public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
public string ImageName { get; set; }
```

In the view

```
@if (Model.ImageName != null) { 
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/uploads/" + Model.ImageName)" alt="" />
}

<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image)
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Image, new { @type = "file", @class = "input-file" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
    </div>
</div>
```

In the controller post action, after checking `ModelState.IsValid`

```
var fileName = "";
// check for a posted file and that it has a size to it before attempting to save the file
if (myViewModel.Image != null && myViewModel.Image.ContentLength > 0)
{
    var currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyymmddhhmmss");
    var fileType = Path.GetExtension(myViewModel.Image.FileName);
    Random random = new Random();
    fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myViewModel.Image.FileName) + "-" + currentDate + random.Next(1, 10000) + fileType;

    // upload the file
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"), fileName);
    myViewModel.Image.SaveAs(path);
}

// for saving to the database on an model entity
if (fileName != "")
{
    entity.ImageName = fileName;
}
```